# how to send multiple values in the form of an object to server

Tags: javascript, java, spring, jsp

I have processed list of SyncStatus object's using List in a jsp page and displayed it in a browser using table. below is my jsp page for displaying list of objects in browser. below is the image of [image: how jsp page looks in browser]

```
    <div class="CSSTableStyle">
    <div class="tableHead">List of Audio Piece Master</div>
    <table id="audiopiece" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" Cellpadding="0">
    <thead>
    <tr><th scope="col">Application Number</th>
        <th scope="col">Date of Birth</th>
        <th scope="col">Mobile Number</th>
        <th scope="col">Channels</th>
        <th scope="col">Sync Status</th>
    </tr></thead>
    <tbody>
    <c:forEach items="${list}" var="audiopiecemast" varStatus="i">
    <tr><td>${audiopiecemast.applnumb}</td>
       <td>${audiopiecemast.dob}</td>
       <td>${audiopiecemast.mob}</td>
       <td><% out.print("All"); %></td>
       <td style="text-align: center;"><a href="syncToProd?syncstatus=${audiopiecemast}"><img src="images/icon_editT.png" /></a> 
</td></tr></c:forEach></tbody></table></div>
```

When i click on save button browser is displaying -

> HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error  Message Failed to convert 
>   value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 
>   'com.bhartiaxa.pojo.SyncStatus'; nested exception is 
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 
>   [java.lang.String] to required type [com.bhartiaxa.pojo.SyncStatus]: 
>   no matching editors or conversion strategy found

my contoller is

```
@RequestMapping(value="syncToProd")
    public ModelAndView syncToProd(HttpSession session, @RequestParam(value="sysnstatus") SyncStatus syncStatus){}
```

My requirement is when i click on save button which is under Sync Status column the entire row data(app no., date of birth, mob no.) has to go to controller in the form of an object. So when i click on save icon, SyncStatus object which i have used this object to display its data in browser should go to spring controller. SyncStatus is an entity object which values will be stored in SYNCSTATUS table in database. Is there any possible solution on how to do it.

Comment: The endpoint is accepting a pojo but you are sending a string as per the stack trace. And there is no converters jabe been configured per trace. It could be helpful if you post how you are submitting the form.

Comment: there is no form.I have used href tag for sending request to controller.If you see the image there are application no. date of birth, mob no. those are the variables of SynStatus pojo class. I have stored SyncStatus class objects in a list and processed the list in a jsp before displying in a browser. There are other variables in Sync Status.I have read them from oracle db and when user click on the pencil image under Sync status appropriate SyncStatus class values should be stored in mysql database. As in the image there are only 3 values. But i have to store all variables in SyncStatus class

Comment: when user clicks on pencil image i have to send that particular SyncStatus object (with related application no.) which i have iterated in jsp page to controller